# Karma, Webpack, Tape & Absolute path issue

Tags: unit-testing, karma-webpack, node.js-tape

This is an interesting situation.

The puzzle is this:
The component's name is TODO

**Controller.js**

```
import Component from 'component';
import View from 'app-folder/components/todo/view';

export default Component.extend({
 viewClass: View
});
```

**View.js**

```
import {LayoutView} from 'backbone.marionette';
import template from 'app-folder/components/todo/template';

export default LayoutView.extend({
  template: template
});
```

I am using Karma, webpack & tape to test out the components. I'm not putting all the functions within the view and component, because it is not necessary for this question. However the question is simple & complex:
How do you deal with absolute path restrictions in an application for doing unit testing

so example:

```
import test from 'tape';

import controller from 'app-folder/components/todo/controller'

test('testing something', (t) => {

  t.end();
});
```

It will return this type of error:

**ERROR in ./components/todo/tests/todo_spec.js**

***Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'app-folder/components/todo/controller' in /Users/username/Documents/projects/app-folder/components/todo/tests***

Because of the path being all weird. Now I wish I could do relative pathing to solve this issue... but due to how it's built, its not possible.

I can't wrap my head around it and definitely having some trouble figuring this one out.

Thanks ahead of time for any advice given!

Comment: Found out the answer to the question. Webpack resolve.alias will work for it just perfectly! {'app-path' : rootPath } and it's good to go!

Comment: Could you share how to solve it?